# What is the origin and meaning of the term "Butt Buddies"?

Tags: meaning, origin-unknown

Today, in the midst of chatting on other SE sites, the term "bum buddies" was used. Some other users took this to be offensive, saying that it was just a slightly less egregious version of "butt buddies". I was not offended by the term, but others informed me that it has homosexual connotations.

I always remember using the term to refer to close friends, almost as a synonym of "bosom buddies".

Can someone guide as the correct usage (so I can avoid using inappropriate terms in the future)? If there is any history on the term that could be useful as well, please include it.

Comment: It's slang, so it could mean different things to different people.  But I would say the most natural intrepretation is "gay lovers" rather than "close friends", and so you should proceed on that basis.

Comment: I think [**bum buddy**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MjsOAQAAMAAJ&q=%22bum+buddies%22&dq=%22bum+buddies%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y) is the "original" version. I also think it's primarily a *British* usage, even though ***buddy*** is essentially American. The superficially more consistent [***butt buddies***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bum+buddies%2Cbutt+buddies&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbum%20buddies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbutt%20buddies%3B%2Cc0) is gaining traction, but they're all offensive, so "correct" doesn't apply.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Did you mark this as "opinion" based then? Is there something I could do to make it less so?

Comment: I did. But to be honest, I don't see *what* you could change to make this a meaningful question. There isn't really any meaning to the idea that coarse homophobic slang like this can be used "appropriately", and because it's primarily a ***spoken*** usage, there's no real point in looking for the earliest ***written*** instances. Though I will just mention that the once-popular BrE ***bumchums*** seems to have some more *specific* connotations in Indian English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was more interested in seeing if I was using the term incorrectly (which given the answers and comments, I was). Since most Stacks like you to have some kind of evidence as well, that is where I thought the "history" portion would come into play. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  
A dictionary or thesaurus may be quite helpful. Your question should include the results of your search. It should also explain why the results were not adequate to answer your question.

Comment: @MetaEd, lots (and lots) of questions here are about proper usage (many slang as well) and some don't even bother asking about etymology or even why they're asking. Is this being closed because of its perceived negative connotations?

Comment: @John Not at all, but the right place for that discussion is either [chat] or [meta].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to NGram Viewer, this is a new term first gaining some prominence in the late 1980's. It would seem to mean based on what I can find, to reference a male homosexual relationship of some varying level of intimacy. However, its usage seems to be that the speaker is simply implying that two things or people appear to be highly bonded, so much so, that tongue-in-cheek, they appear to be lovers.

[image]

I see a reference to it in "[Phrack Magazine](http://phrack.org/issues/44/13.html)" from 1993 in a suggestive, but not literal homosexual way "The software already present on the MCU is all that
is needed, the interface need only support certain emulations
(see Operation Procedures.)  (hmmm... Could Radio Shack and
Northern Telecom be butt buddies?)". It's not clear otherwise how the author intended the usage.

It appears in "ATTITUDE" #48 April 1998, but I don't have this magazine and cannot give you the exact quote. Since this is a men's gay magazine, it appears to be in reference to homosexuality, and maybe specifically male homosexuality.

The term 'bum buddies' appears to have been in usage about 10 years earlier and becoming more ubiquitous during the 80's and 90's before being abandoned in the mid 1990's in favor of 'butt buddies'.

[image]

Comment: Growing up in the 80s and 90s I never heard the term used except with an insult intended. Its not literal, however, any more than saying "that's gay" as slang for "that's bad" is literal.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not the first occurrence, but the South Park episode 'Follow That Egg', which aired in 2005, may have helped make 'butt buddies' a homophobic term in the public consciousness. The episode revolves around the legalisation of same-sex marriage, and the groups that oppose it. The governor of South Park, who has no actual problem with homosexuals getting married, coins the homophobic term 'butt buddies' as a legal 'separate but equal' equivalent to marriage in order to pacify those that feel the word 'marriage' is inappropriate for such a union.

It carries connotations of homosexual men having anal sex. This is reinforced in the episode when a homosexual woman asks "What about lesbians?" (implying that the term is nonsensical to a group not stereotyped as engaging in anal sex), to which the governor replies "Well, like anyone cares about f**king dykes!".

(Apologies for the homophobic language, I am only quoting and do not endorse such opinions!)

Comment: Wow, how young are you guys? Long long before South Park even existed, this term was an insult accusing someone of being gay, or at least insinuating the possibility.

Comment: I'm in my thirties. I'm not saying South Park invented it, I'm saying that it likely helped popularise it. It's a show watched by tens of millions of people around the world - after all, there is evidence to suggest a huge resurgence in the word 'ginger' being used as an insult after a particular episode.