# "Bum buddies" original meaning

Tags: word-usage

***"Bum buddies"***, when I was young [over fifty years ago] was not considered wrong. It meant looking to someone else's back, protecting, hence bum buddy. You watch my back, I'll watch yours.

It's only in more recent times that it has been bastardised to be thought to mean something else. It is thought to have been a term used by soldiers who needed to try to protect each other.

Are there any other Australian oldies out there who can remember?

Comment: Similar: [What is the origin and meaning of the term “Butt Buddies”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346173)

Comment: It might be worthwhile to compare to [bosom buddy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bosom-buddy).